# why the set of continuous complex-valued functions on an open set of $R^n$ is not normable?

Tags: functional-analysis

why the set of continuous complex-valued functions on an open set of $R^n$   is not normable?

I am trying to follow example 1.44 in Rudin's Functional Analysis book, to show that if:

1. $\Omega$ is open set in $R^n$.

   2. $(\Omega, C)$ is the vector space of continuous complex-valued functions from open set $\Omega$ to $C$.
   3. $(K_{n})$ is an increasing sequence of compact sets such that $\bigcup K_{n}=\Omega$.
   4. $(p_{n})$  is a separating family of semi-norms defined by $p_{n}(f)=sup{|f(x)|: x\in K_{n}}$.

   Then it is the locally convex topology that the separating family $(p_{n})$ generates.

Comment: A topological vector space is normable if and only if it is a) Hausdorff [Rudin puts that into the definition of a TVS], b) locally convex, c) locally bounded. Points a) and b) are easy to verify here, so what remains is "$C(\Omega)$ contains no bounded neighbourhood of $0$".

Comment: why it is not locally bounded

Comment: Because a neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ only constrains the value of its members on some fixed compact set $K \subset \Omega$ (depending on the neighbourhood of course), and the functions in $V$ can grow arbitrarily fast outside $K$. Thus no scaling can make all elements of $V$ simultaneously bounded by $1$ on any compact set $L\subset \Omega$ containing $K$ in its interior.